# Subaru Forester XT has a hissing sound under acceleration and lacks power

Tags: automatic-transmission, subaru, turbocharger

I want to buy an 06-08 Forester XT and on Friday I went to test drive an Automatic. Now, I know the auto box isn't the best and the forester weighs a good 300kg/600lbs more than my Astra Coupe, but it just felt like it wasn't going anywhere. It's supposed to have about the same power and torque figures as my Astra, but it felt like it wasn't coming on boost at all and I heard a distinct hissing sound from around 3000RPM.

Now, not being familiar with the forester XT and not having driven an automatic anything before, I can't tell if there was something wrong with it. The salesman seems to think the car is perfect, but it just didn't feel like a 169kW/230BHP car. I didn't feel any sort of push back into my seat when I floored it and as I said, the hissing sound may or may not point to a boost leak, but I don't know. My knowledge is limited to Vauxhall/Opel performance engines so I can't tell what is and what is NOT normal.

Any ideas? How SHOULD the 2006 Forester XT feel under full acceleration?

Comment: I don't have direct experience with the Forester, so will leave a comment. Go and test drive another vehicle of approximately the same year/mileage/options. You may want to drive several different vehicles. Of course the salesman is going to say it's "perfect" ... he wants to sell you a car. There has to be other dealerships in your area which have comparable cars. Don't marry yourself to a car until you are sure. You can always walk away until you've signed on the dotted line.

Comment: I got burned once with my Astra (though admittedly I love it now that I've fixed all the issues). I won't make the same mistake again. I'm actually going to take a drive in a Forester that belongs to a guy on a local Subaru forum. Though he had an exhaust/map done, so it won't help much. Should be fun though ;)

Comment: It sounds like to me the car you are test driving might have a leak on the pressure side. Maybe the BOV or waste gate are having issues ... Your description definitely doesn't sound right.

Comment: It felt EXACTLY like my Astra did when the wastegate solenoid was disconnected (to hide the fact that the turbo was overboosting, putting it in limp mode).

Comment: I think I'd walk away from it, personally.

Comment: Is this a CVT car?  We drove a Forester with a CVT recently and ran away.  It sounded exactly like a slipping clutch.  You'd be able to tell by looking at the tachometer - if the engine revs are staying mostly the same as you accelerate, it has a CVT.

Comment: No, thankfully this was a proper automatic. CVT's are for vegans and other hippies. Though, personally I prefer a manual transmission.

Comment: The boost leak issue could have been simple as a loose hose somewhere. If you were interested in the car, having it looked over by a mechanic, particularly one who specializes in Subarus or turbo-charged vehicles, would have been something to look into.

Comment: I agree. But I'm a little wary because the last car I bought also had a "minor" problem that turned into having to rebuild the turbo at great expense. I'm glad though because just a week later I found an XT manual. They're quite rare, but it's the one I want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there are too many possible reasons that could cause a lack of acceleration. Without inspecting the vehicle, any answer would be highly speculative.

Comment: The question is really about how a Forester should accelerate, not really why it isn't. But It's not really a mechanic question anyway, so no hard feelings.